# How to show that this symmetric matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method

This problem is linked to a physical problem of linear system (structural analysis of a beam with $n+2$ supports), so this matrix $A$ should be invertible. The matrix is $n\times n$ and has elements $a_{i,j}$ given by
$$a_{i,j}=\int_0^L\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)dx$$
for $i,j=${$1,2,...,n$}, $L$ is the length of the beam and 
$$\phi_i(x)=\frac{x(L-x_i)}{L}$$
if $x<x_i$ and
$$\phi_i(x)=\frac{x_i(L-x)}{L}$$
if $x>x_i$.

$x_i$ are the positions of the "internal supports", with $0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n<L$. I already see that $A$ is symmetric, which means that it is diagonalizable. So, if I could prove that $A$ is positive definite then it would have all eingenvalues positive, and since $A$ is diagonalizable then its determinant is the product of its eingenvalues, which means it is invertible.

Comment: What the points $x_i?$  I assume they are $n+2$ evenly spaced nodes at $x_0=0, x_1=L/(n+1),$ $x_2=2L/(n+1),$ etc.    Also, you need to define $\phi_i$ a function of $x.$   The way you currently have it written, $\phi_i$ is a series of constants.

Comment: I've posted below a missing bit. Hope it's still useful. Could you share the source of this problem of supported beam, I'd like to see why the basis functions have to be such and not simply translates of $|x|$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=1$, take $0<x_{1}<x_{2}<...<x_{n}<1$, and consider n functions,
$$\phi_{i}(x)=\begin{cases}
x(1-x_{i}), & x\leq x_{i}\\
x_{i}(1-x), & x>x_{i}
\end{cases}=x(\tfrac{1}{2}-x_{i})+\tfrac{1}{2}x_{i}-\tfrac{1}{2}\vert x-x_{i}\vert$$

The functions $\{\phi_i\}$ are linear independent. Were they linearly *dependent*, one of them $\phi_k$ would be a linear combination of the others **differentiable** at $x=x_k$, contradicting the fact that $\phi_k$ itself is not differentiable at $x=x_k$. ([Prove function space is linearly independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415426/prove-function-space-is-linearly-independent))

Introducing the inner product as in your question we then make use of the key property of the Gramian matrix $G_{ij}=\langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle$: "a set of vectors is linearly independent *if and only if* the Gram determinant (the determinant of the Gram matrix) is non-zero" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $A$ is positive-definite for "reasonable" basis functions $\phi$.

Hint: for any vector $v$,

\begin{align*}
v^TAv &= \sum_{i,j} v_i \left(\int_0^L \phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)\,dx \right)v_j \\
&= \int_0^L \sum_{i,j} v_i\phi_i(x)v_j\phi_j(x)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^L \left(\sum_i v_i\phi_i(x)\right)^2\,dx
\end{align*}

and can you take it from here? You should now also see the conditions necessary on $\phi$ for $A$ to be positive-definite.

Stepping back, you should recognize that the $A$ matrix represents an $L^2$ inner product on the discrete function space spanned by the basis elements $\phi$, and so must be positive-definite.

Comment: "reasonable" means simply that the $\phi_i$ are linearly independent

Comment: @daw Yes, if you are appropriately precise in what you mean by "linearly independent" -- for instance you cannot have $\phi$s where a nonzero linear combination vanishes a.e.