# Prove function space is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ the space of all funcions $f:Ŗ\rightarrow R$. Prove that the ten functions defined by $x\rightarrow |x-1|$,$x\rightarrow |x-2|$,....,$x\rightarrow |x-10|$ are linearly independent.

I need some help here. Although I know the definitions of linear independency, and vector spaces, I'm confused because the exercise isn't that clear, and so I don't know how apply them in this case.
(I tried with $a_1|x-1|+a_2|x-2|+...+a_{10}|x-10|=0$ but couldn't get to anything).

Any tips or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little calculus is helpful here. Suppose to the contrary they are linearly dependent. Then one of the functions, say $|x-i|$, is a linear combination of the others. But all the others are differentiable at $x=i$, so any linear combination of them is differentiable at $x=i$. However, $|x-i|$ is not differentiable at $x=i$.

Comment: One could reword, erasing explicit mention of derivative, looking at $f(i+0.1)-f(i)$ and $f(i)-f(i-0.1)$.  Same geometric basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

You need to get rid of $\vert \cdot \vert$. For this, take $$f(x)=a_1 \vert x-1\vert + \dots +a_{10}\vert x -10\vert$$ and suppose $f$ that is always vanishing.

For $x<1$ uou have $$f(x)=-(a_1+\dots +a_{10})x+\alpha$$ As $f$ is always vanishing $a_1+\dots +a_{10}=0$. Now look at $f$ for $1<x<2$, and in particular to the coefficient in front of $x$.

You should be able to deduce that $a_1=0$. And by induction that all the $a_i$ aequal to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by vanishing? that it is equal to zero no matter the values of x? (sorry but english is not my first language)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.